# Calculating percent discount on Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

ive been trying to work out this problem for an hour or so and just cant figure it out. May someone point me to the right direction please? I am working with the data from OE schema off of Oracle SQL Developer.

I need to show the product category name for products that have the largest % discount off of the list_price.

This is my code:

```
SELECT    ct.category_name, ROUND((pi.list_price pi.min_price)*100/pi.list_Price) AS Percent_Discount
FROM        oe.product_information pi JOIN oe.categories_tab ct ON pi.category_id = ct.category_id
GROUP BY  ct.category_name, ROUND((pi.list_price-pi.min_price)*100/pi.list_Price)
ORDER BY  ROUND((pi.list_price-pi.min_price)*100/pi.list_Price) desc;
```

[Here is an image of my results of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBi1Q.png)

The results actually go all the way down to 150ish or so which includes every single product.

My question is: How do I get it so my percent number is two decimal places instead of it being rounded into a whole number? I understand I used the round statement, but I only did it because without it, the numbers are about 15 digits.
Also, do you think my code is answering the problem correctly? I feel like i should only show the top 10 or 20 category names with the biggest discount. Is there anyway I could do that instead of listing all of them?

Answer (score 1):

`ROUND()` takes a second argument, which is the number of decimal places you want (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm)).  So:

```
SELECT ct.category_name,
       MAX(ROUND((pi.list_price - pi.min_price)*100/pi.list_Price, 2)) AS Percent_Discount
FROM oe.product_information pi JOIN
     oe.categories_tab ct
     ON pi.category_id = ct.category_id
GROUP BY ct.category_name
ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

Note:  If you want one row per category then `category_name` should be the only key in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you so much again! Just for clarification, the max statement is used to answer the largest % discount part of the question? And im not quite understanding how come you only used "2" in the ORDER BY part, may you please explain that one for me?

Comment: @KurtLee . . . The `max()` is to answer the "largest % discount".   The "2" is actually just a shorthand because I didn't want to type `Percent_Discount`.